# MS Access select from two tables

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, subquery

I have 2 MS ACCESS tables and want to build a select that will return 3 columns; table1.name table1.dept and the value in 1 of 3 columns from table 2 based on the table1 position column. Table1.position only has 3 possible values and each value determines the table2 column to use.

table1

name dept position

table2

dept posval1 posval2 posval3

My select would look something like this example.

```
select a.name, a.dept, b.((if a.pos = "eng", b.posval1) OR (if a.pos = "research", b.posval2) OR (if a.pos = "dv1", b.posval3))
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.dept = b.dept
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN clause to link on `dept` fields instead of WHERE. Use nested IIf() to select appropriate posval.

```
SELECT a.name, a.dept, 
    IIf(pos="eng", posval1, IIf(pos="research", posval2, IIf(pos="dv1", posval3, "None"))) AS Position
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.dept = b.dept;
```

Or use Switch() function.

```
SELECT a.name, a.dept, 
    Switch(pos="eng",posval1, pos="research",posval2, pos="dv1",posval3) AS Position
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.dept = b.dept;
```

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. If you really like it, can upvote as well.